# How to plot 3-dimensional points as an object in POV-Ray?

Tags: 3d, povray

I have a set of three dimensional points, and I want to create the surface that fits these points in POV-Ray. Is it possible? I could not find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent each point by a sphere or a blob to get an impression of the surface. You may be able to generate a .df3 density file and render that as an isosurface. Safest route is search for a tool that triangulates the point cloud into a mesh and render that with POV-Ray